# Run background task from MainScreen in BlackBerry?

Tags: java, blackberry, background-process

The issue is how do i make an inception in BlackBerry?

Background: I need to run background service (No Screen Application) after i register a client, after that i need to run safely on the thread.

Thank you very much in advance , code example will be really appreciated.

Comment: You can make your application as Autostart Application and can run it in background when the device boots.

Comment: As i have wrote, i want to run it from UI screen!

Comment: Then you can create a Thread class that contains your code that you want to run in the Background and call that class on the Load of the UI Screen.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a runnable class that extends thread. (Note, there may be other ways to do this, but this one works.

So you'll need something like

```
public class BackgroundTask extends Thread{


    private Object _screen;

    public BackgroundTask()
    {

    }

    /**
    * Implementation of Thread.
    */
    public void run()
    {  
        //Do some background task
    }
```

Now from your main screen, you simply need to call it.

```
    //Start my background task
new BackgroundTask().start()
```

Start is a method inherited from the parent Thread class, so it'll take care of spawning a thread for you.
Hope this helps.

Comment: In hindsight it's not necessary. It gives your thread access to your main screen if you wanted to push an update to it, but really it's optional. Apologies for the ambiguity (I'm new at BB programming myself)

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
    public void run() {
        // Code for the background service.
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Blackberry-way to do it is [to use invokeLater()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html):

```
        int _id = -1;
        Application _app = UiApplication.getUiApplication();

        ...

        _id = _app.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do something - in 10 seconds
                _id = -1;
            }
        }, 10*1000L, false);
```